# Setting path in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, directory, environment-variables

In Ubuntu 13.10 I installed :

[stable_Ubuntu-13.10-i686.deb](http://files.ettus.com/binaries/uhd_stable/latest_stable/uhd_003.007.000-1-stable_Ubuntu-13.10-i686.deb) and [Ubuntu-13.10-i686.deb](http://files.ettus.com/binaries/gnuradio/latest_stable/gnuradio_3.7.2.1-77_Ubuntu-13.10-i686.deb), but when starting `GNURadio` the following message appears :

```
Cannot import gnuradio.

Is the python path environment variable set correctly?
All OS: PYTHONPATH

Is the library path environment variable set correctly?
Linux: LD_LIBRARY_PATH
Windows: PATH
MacOSX: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

- How can I set python path and the library path environment variable to the correct value?

Answer (score 2):

First try running this command to configure the libraries:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

If that doesn't solve it, you'll need to add these lines to `~/.profile` file:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

This assumes that you actually have python2.7 installed and that `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` is not empty. See [here](http://gnuradio.4.n7.nabble.com/Cannot-import-gnuradio-td42045.html) for more details.